# Running Chromium.app crashes as it cannot find some specific system dylibs

Tags: xcode, macos, chromium, dylib, dynamic-loading

I have built chromium from https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkcr/docs/mac_build_instructions.md

I am able to successfully build and run on the machine that i built the code but not able to run it on any other mac.

I want to be able to distribute the application file.

The application crashes because its not able to find some system libraries which load dynamically.(libsystem_kernel.dylib , libsystem_pthread.dylib, libsystem_c.dylib ,libdyld.dylib ).

These dylibs can be found in /usr/lib folder on Mac OSX

Any suggestion on distribution of the app?